# Changing values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to learn by tinkering with a webpage.
So it is a button and when you click it, it gains a child with the id oddsInput. I cant get the values to change

```
function checksettings(payout) {
$('#oddsPayout').click();
var iodds = $('#oddsInput');
iodds.value = payout;
// $('glyphicon glyphicon-ok btn btn-success').click();
}

checksettings(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `$('#oddsInput')` is a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). It doesn't have a `value` property.

Either access the first DOM element in the jQuery object:

```
iodds[0].value = payout;
// or
$('#oddsInput')[0].value = payout;
```

or, since it's a jQuery object, use the [`.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
iodds.val(payout);
// or
$('#oddsInput').val(payout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#oddsInput').val(payout);
```